# List comprehension with multiple commands

Tags: python, list-comprehension, filepath

I am creating output files for list of files. At the end of my routine, I would like to obtain a list of the output file names which I can achieve using the for block below. Is there a clean way to do such a thing using list comprehension or is this not a good time for comprehension?

```
import os

names = []
for file in f_list:
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    names.append(f"{base}_env{ext}")
```

The below works but if I can't get rid of the duplicated call of os.path.splitext, I'm not really excited by this.

`[f"{os.path.splitext(file)[0]}_env{os.path.splitext(file)[1]}" for file in list]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use map:

```
import os

names = [f"{base}_env{ext}" for base,ext in map(os.path.splitext,f_list)]
```

Comment: Perfect! I like the simplicity. This is exactly what I was looking for but didn't know how to implement. I think I'll be reading up on `map()` as well. Seems like something that will have a lot of use cases.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there's a better approach, but it looks like `str.format` with list unpacking via the `*` operator could work:

```py
import os

f_list = ['hello.txt', 'world.json']

names = ['{}_env{}'.format(*os.path.splitext(file)) for file in f_list]
```

With Python 3.8+, you also combine the walrus `:=` operator with f-strings (which should be slightly more efficient):

```py
names = [f'{(p := os.path.splitext(file))[0]}_env{p[1]}' for file in f_list]
```

Output:

```
['hello_env.txt', 'world_env.json']
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I hadn't thought about going back to the `str.format`. Probably because my footing with unpacking lists via `*` is still a bit shaky. This certainly accomplishes what I asked. If I could mark all the answers I see right now as correct, I would, but I must choose and I like the cleanliness and readability of using map.

Comment: No problem. If it's helpful, I also did a quick test and confirmed that `map` is indeed the most efficient approach here (but the second approach listed comes very close indeed)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [pathlib](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/) instead of manipulating paths as plain strings?

If you turn your existing list of file path strings into a list of Path objects...

```
from pathlib import Path

original_paths = [Path(file_name) for file_name in f_list]
```

...Then your modified paths can be constructed like this, using the [`with_stem()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_stem) method:

```
new_paths = [path.with_stem(f'{path.stem}_env') for path in original_paths]
```

(The "stem" is the part of the file's name without its suffix.)

Your mileage may vary, but I find that pathlib's descriptive method and attribute names make it a lot easier to tell what path-related code does at a glance, which comes in particularly handy when you're looking over your own code months later.

Comment: I hadn't thought about using pathlib and was unaware of the `with_stem()` method. I don't have anything against using libraries when the alternatives are poor, but I really like the use case for `map()` that was pointed out.